# How to add an AutoFill option to a text field in Flutter?

Tags: sql, flutter, autocomplete, autofill, sqflite

I have a SQflite database in Flutter with names stored in it and would like to offer these names from the database in a Text Field at another place (see images) automatically as an AutoFill option. In addition, the names have other information that should then also be automatically inserted / recommended as an AutoFill Option in the other text fields to make the creation of new users much easier. Unfortunately this sounds like a lot of work, and unfortunately I have no idea how to do this.

These are my files:

Main Page:
[The AutoFill option should be displayed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5PuM.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bespannungen/pages/sql_Auftrag.dart';

import 'dart:async';

class UserAuftrag extends StatefulWidget
{
  const UserAuftrag({Key? key}) : super(key : key);

  @override
  State<UserAuftrag> createState() => _UserAuftragState();
}


class _UserAuftragState extends State<UserAuftrag> 
{
  // Journals erstellen
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _journals = [];

  // Aktualisieren der Datenbank
  void _refreshJournals() async
  {
    final data = await SQLHelperAuftrag.getItems();
    setState( ()
    { 
      _journals = data;
    });
  }

  // Datenbank beim starten laden
  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    _refreshJournals();
    print("..Anzahl an Items ${_journals.length}");
  }

  // Variablen als Controller in denen Name, Schläger etc. abgespeichert und abgerufen werden
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _schlagerController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _saiteController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _saitenHaerteController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _sonstigesController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    // Eingabe in die Datenbank hinzufügen
    Future<void> _addItem() async
    {
      await SQLHelperAuftrag.createItem
      (_nameController.text, 0, _schlagerController.text, _saiteController.text, _saitenHaerteController.text, _sonstigesController.text);
      _refreshJournals();
    }

    // Eingabe in der Datenbank updaten
    Future<void> _updateItem(int id) async
    {
      await SQLHelperAuftrag.updateItem
      (
        id, 
        0,
        _nameController.text, 
        _schlagerController.text, 
        _saiteController.text, 
        _saitenHaerteController.text, 
        _sonstigesController.text
      );
      _refreshJournals();
    }

    // Eingabe aus der Datenbank löschen
    void _deleteItem(int id) async
    {
      await SQLHelperAuftrag.deleteItem(id);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Eintrag erfolgreich gelöscht'),));
      _refreshJournals();
    }

      // Abruf eines Eintrags in der Datenbank / Erstellen eines Eintrags + Erstellen / Aufrufen des PopUps
    void _showForm(int? id) async
    {
      if (id != null)
      {
        final existingJournal = _journals.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] == id);
        _nameController.text = existingJournal['Name'];
        _schlagerController.text = existingJournal['Schläger'];
        _saiteController.text = existingJournal['Saite'];
        _saitenHaerteController.text = existingJournal['Härte'];
        _sonstigesController.text = existingJournal['Sonstiges'];
      }

      // Eingabefeld öffnen
      showModalBottomSheet
      (
        context: context,
        elevation: 5,
        isScrollControlled: true,

        // Einrichten des Containers für die Eingabefelder
        builder: (_) => Container
        (
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 15, right: 15, bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 350),
          child: Column
          (
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,

            // Eingabefelder
            children: 
            [
              // Eingabefeld 1
              TextField
              (          
                controller: _nameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
              const SizedBox
              (
                height: 10,
              ),

              // Eingabefeld 2
              TextField
              (
                controller: _schlagerController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Schläger'),
              ),
              const SizedBox
              (
                height: 20,
              ),

              // Eingabefeld 3
              TextField
              (
                controller: _saiteController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Saite'),
              ),
              const SizedBox
              (
                height: 20,
              ),

              // Eingabefeld 4
              TextField
              (
                controller: _saitenHaerteController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Bespannungshärte'),
              ),
              const SizedBox
              (
                height: 20,
              ),

              // Eingabefeld 5
              TextField
              (
                controller: _sonstigesController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Sonstiges'),
              ),
              const SizedBox
              (
                height: 20,
              ),

              ElevatedButton
              (
                onPressed: () async
                {
                  if (id == null)
                  {
                    await _addItem();
                  }
                  if (id != null)
                  {
                    await _updateItem(id);
                  }

                  //Leeren der Textfelder
                  _nameController.text = '';
                  _schlagerController.text = '';
                  _saiteController.text = '';
                  _saitenHaerteController.text = '';
                  _sonstigesController.text = '';

                  //Schließen des Fensters
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }, 
                child: Text(id == null ? 'Erstellen' : 'Update'),
              )

            ],
          )
        )
      );
    }

    return Scaffold
    (
      // Grundeinstellungen Design
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 20),

      // Top AppBar
      appBar: AppBar
      (
        title: const Text('Aufträge'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: 
        [
          IconButton(onPressed: () {_refreshJournals();}, icon: const Icon(Icons.sync))
        ],
      ),

      // Einzelnen Karten mit Einträgen
      body: ListView.builder
      (
        itemCount: _journals.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card
        (
          color: Colors.red,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 3),
          child: ListTile
          (
            title: Text(_journals[index]['Name']),
            subtitle: Text('${_journals[index]['Schläger']} / ${_journals[index]['Saite']} / ${_journals[index]['Härte']} / ${_journals[index]['Sonstiges']}'),
            trailing: SizedBox
            (
              width: 98,
              child: Row
              (
                children: 
                [
                  IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.edit), onPressed: () => _showForm(_journals[index]['id']), iconSize: 20,),
                  IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: () => _deleteItem(_journals[index]['id']),),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
        )
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton
      (
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => _showForm(null),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The SQflite database of names to be suggested:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;

class SQLHelperSchlager 
{
  static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async
  {
    await database.execute
    (
      """CREATE TABLE items
      (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        Name TEXT,
        Schläger TEXT,
        Saite TEXT,
        Härte TEXT,
        Sonstiges TEXT,
        createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      )
      """
    );
  }

  // Check ob Datenbank bereits existiert + Check ob Tabelle bereits erstellt wurde
  static Future<sql.Database> db() async
  {
    return sql.openDatabase
    (
      'schlager2.db',
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (sql.Database database, int version) async
      {
        await createTables(database);
      }
    );
  }

  // Eintrag in der Datenbank abspeichern
  static Future<int> createItem(String name, String schlagerName, String? saitenName, String? saitenHaerte, String? sonstiges) async
  {
    final db = await SQLHelperSchlager.db();

    final data = 
    {
      'Name': name, 
      'Schläger': schlagerName, 
      'Saite': saitenName, 
      'Härte': saitenHaerte, 
      'Sonstiges': sonstiges
    };
    final id = await db.insert
    (
      'items', 
      data, 
      conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace
    );
    return id;
  }

  // Automatisches Laden der Datenbank beim Start der App
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getItems() async
  {
    final db = await SQLHelperSchlager.db();
    return db.query('items', orderBy: "name");
  }

  // Element anhand der ID aus der Datenbank abfragen
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getItem(int id) async
  {
    final db = await SQLHelperSchlager.db();
    return db.query('items', where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id], limit: 1);
  }

  // Element in der Datenbank anhand der ID bearbeiten
  static Future<int> updateItem(int id, String name, String schlagerName, String? saitenName, String? saitenHaerte, String? sonstiges) async
  {
    final db = await SQLHelperSchlager.db();

    final data = 
    {
      'Name': name, 
      'Schläger': schlagerName, 
      'Saite': saitenName, 
      'Härte': saitenHaerte, 
      'Sonstiges': sonstiges,
      'createdAt': DateTime.now().toString()
    };

    final result =
    await db.update('items', data, where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    return result;
  }

  // Element aus der Datenbank anhand der ID löschen
  static Future<void> deleteItem(int id) async
  {
    final db = await SQLHelperSchlager.db();
    try
    {
      await db.delete("items", where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    } catch (err)
    {
      debugPrint("Etwas ist beim löschen schief gelaufen: $err");
    }
  }

}
```

If anyone needs more information i will add it i guess
Thanks!

I have already seen that there is a plugin for Flutter where you can give an AutoFill option using a list stored in a json file, however I don't know how the json file should access the SQflite database and how I should make the other text fields autocomplete based on the name

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html  you need a full text search capable API where u can post part of name and return a list from server that u can show to users. and provide a small exmaple of what input u expect from user and what suggetion u want to show to user